# Selecting features by characters contained in a text string

Tags: qgis, select-by-attribute, text, string

Is there a way to select the features of a map by finding text within an attribute table? For example, if several features are listed as "Nature preserve" under a column called "Category", can I select all these features using an expression like, `"Category" contains '*nature*`', or something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the "select by expression" tool with the following expression

`regexp_match("Category",'ature') > 0`

will select all features where the string "ature" is found in the column "Category". I omitted the `n` because I actually don't know whether regexp is case-sensitive.

Replace "Category" with the actual name of your column.

The expression checks for  `> 0` because `regexp_match` returns the place where the string you search for starts, or `0` if the string isn't part of the attribute. So, everything where a value unlike `0` is returned contains the string you searched for.